# How to avoid overlay between two divs when using position: absolute in CSS

Tags: html, css

As you see this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvQpaY) link, I'm trying to avoid overlay between the two divs with their class name of box-container. As the red rectangle is position: absolute, the box-container only counts the black rectangle as its overall height.

Since I need to place the red rectangle above the black rectangle, I have to use position: absolute, but how can I let box-container count the red rectangle as its overall height?

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.box-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.box-text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.box-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box-text"></div>
    <div class="box-image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box-text"></div>
    <div class="box-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use `position: relative` instead?

Comment: If I use `position: relative`, then how can I place `box-image` on `box-text`?

Comment: Change the order in the html...

Comment: You would have to toy a bit with the `z-index` and move parts as you need

Comment: No; look at the answer; the `z-index` is just to make sure that the `box-image` is *above* the `box-text`; I just mentioned that in case you would have to make changes there; but just like with `position: absolute` you now just have to move the red box using `top, left, bottom, right`

Comment: you can use float to achieve this effect https://codepen.io/XiaoYyyy/pen/WmYMzM

Answer (score 0):

It would end up looking a bit like this using `position: relative`; now the red box is also part of the total height; you can move it around and modify it as you need.

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}

.box-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.box-text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.box-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: -100px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box-text"></div>
    <div class="box-image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box-text"></div>
    <div class="box-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to place the red box to the very right end?

Comment: You can place it anywhere you need; you just have to provide the right amount of units to move; remember `position: relative` just makes you able to move the element starting from its initial position; if you want to move it `100px` above from where it was you can use `bottom:100px` or `top:-100px`

Comment: I see, then how do I let the red box know where is the very right end? As I need to apply this to responsive designs. `box-container` has different width sizes depending on the screen's width.

Comment: I would suggest using functions like `calc()` and similar to calculate the size of the screen and such; but that is another situation really; either that or restructure your HTML and CSS a bit; that'd be a different question honestly